# Develop a reporting tool in NodeJS or PHP Laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, reporting, saas

I'm looking forward to develop a reporting tool for a telecom data, it will basically be a lot of readonly db calls and based on which a lot of reports will be developed like

- number of calls
- top calling users
- top calling destinations
- etc

The db is in Postgresql.  i've decided to use PHP Laravel but I'm being advised to develop it node.JS. I've search on the internet but i'm not able to justify laravel.

- There wont be a lot of concurrent users
- It's a SaaS application but each company's deployment will be separate.

Looking forward to get help from experienced people what's the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the choice of the programming language depends on multiple factors here.

- Large Data Processing - I have worked on NodeJS processing a large amount of data in memory
  and out of memory, it is not the obvious choice here but it can be done with some smart choices like data streaming and processing data in chunks. I have not really worked on PHP data processing, but you will have to face similar challenges in PHP, and since PHP runs on a server viz. Nginx or Apache you will have to make sure the server can handel the load with some extra config.
- Technical expertise - If your development **team is comfortable with language** i.e PHP and have experience working in PHP, then that's what you should go for. Because I think no matter the language you use, the output will depend on the design patterns and solutions you implement to produce the desired result and how well your code is optimized.

> Let me try to explain with a real-world dilemma  - *If you are an artist and want to choose your tools to create a masterpiece would you go for new tools which you are not comfortable with or the tried and tested ones which you have used to create art in past ?*

- Deployment Strategy - This is something which will vary as per project. In the case of comparison, I feel it is very **easy to build, integrate and deploy a node** application. Whereas it takes a little bit more time to get the PHP applications up on server and deployments. ( my views are based on my experiences with docker deployments, please take them with a pinch of salt)
- Integration with database - In this case, PHP may shine over Nodejs, the only reason I feel is that the amount of **ready to use database integration** plugins and many of these plugins may have reporting interfaces as well. On the other hand, you may have to do a bit of coding in case of Node to get there, that said there may be some modules available in Node as well which I am not aware of.

*These are a few factors which come to my mind before I decide on any tool or technology. Please do not consider this as statements or criticism of any language or tools. These are my personal views based on my experience so far. Thanks*

oh, Almost forgot ... If your lead or manager feels you should go with Nodejs , then there's no arguing with that my friend :D  ( pun intended)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer but i'm looking for a more technical convincing answer,  like if there is any obvious choice like for example in case of a chat application node.js is the way to go. so in my scenario both have pros and cons or do we have an obvious winner ?

Comment: I think we can conclude that it is going to be a simialr excersie in the end if you go with either of technologies, as I cannot see any clear advantage of one over the other. 
The only advantage you can have is if you are familiar with one particular language or tool you can go ahead and experiment with it to get best results.